# filter out all datetime and integer values from a column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a string

```
04/09/2018 06:21:38 101342 CHARLESD JOHNSON:713-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO  06/09/2018 08:41:38 101345 KHARLESD KOHNSON:813-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO  08/09/2018 09:41:38 10356 THARLESD TOHNSON:913-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO
```

I want output like

```
DateTime1            |  EmpID
04/09/2018 06:21:38    101342
06/09/2018 08:41:38    101345
08/09/2018 09:41:38    10356
```

Please help

Comment: Have you made *any* attempts to try and do this yourself? What code did you use to try; please post it. Why SQL Server? SQL Server is far from the best tool for string manipulation. You would be far better using a language that at least support Regex. The one thing you've tagged is probably one of the worst things to try and achieve this with, however, regardless it's unlikely to be pretty.

Comment: I think it would be better if you use a language other than T-SQL to do this. For example you could use C# (CLR is supported in SQL Server).

Comment: Doable, but not efficiently. Hint: `PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', ...)`, with a loop and a cursor or a recursive CTE and oh my word I've gone cross-eyed.

Answer (score 1):

Create the function **PatternSplitLoop** from this awesome article:

[Splitting Strings Based on Patterns](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/)

and execute the following:

```
declare @tab table (string varchar(max))
insert into @tab select '04/09/2018 06:21:38 101342 CHARLESD JOHNSON:713-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO 06/09/2018 08:41:38 101345 KHARLESD KOHNSON:813-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO  08/09/2018 09:41:38 10356 THARLESD TOHNSON:913-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO '
select left(item, 19) DateTime1, substring(item, 20, len(item)) EmpID 
from @tab t
cross apply [dbo].[PatternSplitLoop](string, '%[0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%') f
where matched = 1
```

Output:

[image: Output after running the query]

Answer (score 0):

XML split version:

```
DECLARE @Val NVARCHAR(MAX) = '04/09/2018 06:21:38 101342 CHARLESD JOHNSON:713-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO  06/09/2018 08:41:38 101345 KHARLESD KOHNSON:813-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO  08/09/2018 09:41:38 10356 THARLESD TOHNSON:913-269-1878 CALL WHEN WE GET A PO '

SELECT @Val = '<a>' + REPLACE(@Val, ' ', '</a><a>') + '</a>';
DECLARE @Xml XML = CONVERT(XML, @Val);

DECLARE @ValTable TABLE
(   
    ROWNUM INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Val NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT into @ValTable
(Val)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(64)') AS Val  
    FROM   @Xml.nodes('/a') T(c)
) a
WHERE LEN(Val) <> 0 
    AND (TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, Val) IS NOT NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(TIME, Val) IS NOT NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(INT, Val) IS NOT NULL);

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(a.Val, ' ', b.Val)) AS DateTime1, c.Val AS EmpId
FROM @ValTable a
JOIN @ValTable b
--Date and Time rows, B is time row
    ON TRY_CONVERT(TIME, a.Val) IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(TIME, b.Val) IS NOT NULL AND b.ROWNUM = a.ROWNUM + 1
-- Int rows
JOIN @ValTable c
    ON TRY_CONVERT(INT, c.Val) IS NOT NULL AND c.ROWNUM = a.RowNum + 2;
```